# Old variabe sent from form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, server

I have a from that has NEW a hidden variable. Lets say the variable from previous submission was 2.

```
<?php echo $variable = 3;
echo $variable; //displays 3
?>
<form action="functions/store.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="variable" value="<?php echo $variable ;?>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

When running the code to store it in the data base, it stores the variable form the previus submission: 2. Why is that. The code I in store.php run is:

```
$variable= $_POST['variable'];
echo $variable; //displays 2. Should display 3

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT BlahBlahBlah... //other code
```

I have no idea what's going on even unset($variable) before $_POST does not work.

It worked fine for a while then, it started to behave like this. Even tried on other browser - same result

Comment: is there a $_POST['set_id']?

Comment: yes it should be `$_POST['variable']`

Comment: Sory it's a typo. Was trying to put the orignal variables out. it's $_POST['variable']

Comment: Where is the insert in the code?

Comment: I have a suggestion Ctrl+F find `$variable` check that it is modified between

Comment: all of the variables seem correct